# move first two characters of a string after a specific character in a string

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I want to reformat some genome changes so I can use a certain tool. How can I move the first two characters of a string after a colon in the same string?

For example:
g.chr17:7577121G>A must become  chr17:g.7577121G>A
g.chr3:52712586T>C must become  chr3:g.52712586T>C

There is probably a very straightforward way to do this with gsub an paste, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this option:

```
input <- "g.chr17:7577121G>A"
input <- sub("^([^.]+\\.)([^:]+:)", "\\2\\1", input)
input

[1] "chr17:g.7577121G>A"
```

The pattern might require some explanation:

```
^                from the beginning of the input
    ([^.]+\\.)   match and capture any non dot characters up to and including
                 the first dot
    ([^:]+:)     then match and capture any non colon characters up to and
                 including the first colon
```

Then, we replace with these two captured groups reversed.  In this case, the first group is `g.`, and the second group is `chr17:`.  So, the replacement string would then start with `chr17:g.`, followed by whatever was already there.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `sub` with 3 capture groups

```
sub("(^.{2})(.*:)(.*)", "\\2\\1\\3", x)
#[1] "chr17:g.7577121G>A" "chr3:g.52712586T>C"
```

`^.{2}` - First capture group are first two characters.

`.*:` - Second capture group is the string till colon.

`.*` - Third capture group is the remaining string.

and now we arrange these groups in the order 2-1-3.

**data**

```
x <- c("g.chr17:7577121G>A", "g.chr3:52712586T>C")
```

Comment: No need for a third captuee group.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, I saw that in your answer but me being a noob in regex was bit difficult for me to digest.

Comment: I certainly don't consider you to be a noob on the R tag +1.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one without a regex

```
v1 <- strsplit(input, "[.:]")[[1]]
paste0(v1[2], ":", v1[1], ".", v1[3])
#[1] "chr17:g.7577121G>A"
```

#### data

```
input <- "g.chr17:7577121G>A"
```